# list-style-type no showing

Tags: css, list

bullets from list-style type not showing up.  Not only does the CSS, in no place declare list-style-type: none, but I've even declared list-style-type: disc for the section being described.    Even opening firebug and the equivalents, it's clear that the bullets should be showing.  Very confused.  Happening in all browsers.

I'm talking about the div #product-list next to the image.

PS please no comments on how atrociously ugly it is.  Required to exactly replicate their previous site.

Comment: You might want to paste the relevant markup here to make it easier to tell which list you're talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of the `display` property, it is set to `block` (and even `inline`), it needs to be `list-item`, the default values on `<li>`s

Comment: WOW.  Banging my head on the table. Really need to step back from things sometimes.  Thanks.