# list-style-type not working on iOS Chrome ver. 87.0

Tags: css, ios, list, google-chrome

**Target**:

Want the list style to look same on both desktop and iOS Chrome.

**Question**:

1. iOS Chrome didn't render `list-style-type` as I saw on desktop Chrome; `li`'s display property had set to `list-item`, where did I mess up?
2. Why `list-style-type` isn't working on iOS Chrome?

---

Here's the source codes:

```css
#arrow li {
  list-style-type: "\21A0";
}

#thumbs-up li {
  list-style-type: "\1F44D";
}

#svg-arrow li {
  list-style-image: url("https://svgshare.com/i/WCG.svg");
}
```

```html
<ul id="default">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Cherry</li>
</ul>

<ul id="arrow">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Cherry</li>
</ul>

<ul id="thumbs-up">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Cherry</li>
</ul>

<ul id="svg-arrow">
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Cherry</li>
</ul>
```

Desktop Chrome (ver. 89.0.4389.114) renders the code as I wished:
[screenshot for desktop chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSdnK.png)

While Chrome on iOS (ver. 87.0.4280.163) doesn't:
[screenshot for iOS chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amSYz.png)

---

Had searched the keywords "list style not work" and found some posts, but the answers didn't solve my problem:

- [Overflow and list style type doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821946/overflow-and-list-style-type-doesnt-work)
- [list-style-type no showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298790/list-style-type-no-showing)

I didn't change the `display` property of `li`, and Chrome's user agent stylesheet had set `li`'s display property as `list-item`.